# What's the best item to keep a wizard alive?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, wizard

Right now my party is 5th level and we just spent some downtime crafting. But I can tell the encounters are aiming at my wizard a little more since I'm dealing consistent damage now.

Current party is Cleric, Rogue, Paladin, Ranger, & Wizard. I know the paladin can revivify in a few more levels and of course there's the cleric as is. What I'm worried about is the Cleric going down and then I go down as the Wizard.

What's the best item near my level that would keep me alive or revive me?

My current hp is 27, I have a lot of spells that I copied from scrolls. I already have mirror image, fly, mage armor and shield to name a few.

Comment: Please use the edit button on the original post to update it instead of posting your changes in a new question post. Thanks!

Comment: That post was closed. So I asked it with a more narrow aspect..

Comment: I thought that when a post is closed it couldn't be opened?

Comment: @VirgilMoore Closed posts can be reopened.  If you edit your other post, the process of reopening it starts automatically.

Comment: I've un-marked this as a duplicate, so it can be home of the second question that was put in the original.

Comment: I think it would be relevant to show us your spell list. And also your HP and AC, to a lesser extent.

Comment: I don't think this can be answered.  You can stay alive by killing enemies first, by having AC/saves/resists, by controlling people/the battlefield - in fact one might say the vast majority of all PC options are "to keep you alive."

Answer (score 6):

One of the best magic items for increasing survivability is the periapt of wound closure. 
It automatically stabilises you at the start of your turn if you're dying, and hit dice recover twice as many hit points.

With this item, if you ever get knocked unconscious, you only need to survive until the start of your next turn, at which point you will stabilise. This will prevent your character from dying to death saving throws, but your party will still need to defeat the encounter to survive.

It will also give you a lot more bang for your buck in terms of recovering HP on short rests. You effectively get twice as many hit dice, allowing you to keep going for longer without worrying about HP.

And the item is definitely "near your level", the periapt of wound closure is an uncommon magic item. If your DM follows the guidelines in the DMG, you should be able to craft it.

Comment: Great answer until the last sentence. Item crafting guidelines in 5e are "get out there and look for an existing one." Crafting is never a "should be able to" in 5e.

Comment: I've got to disagree, @DerekStucki. Admittedly, the presence of *any* magical items is a setting detail under the purview of the DM. But xanderh clearly said "if your DM follows..." in which case the rest is absolutely correct. If the DM is using the crafting rules on DMG pp.128-129, then the level 5 wizard meets the level prerequisite to create an uncommon item and (presumably) 20 downtime days and 500gp aren't beyond his means.

Comment: And have a pattern for the item, which is one level of rarity higher.

Comment: @DerekStucki Wait, where does it say the rarity for patterns? I don't remember seeing that anywhere.

Comment: @DerekStucki In fact, looking in the DMG, the recipe is mentioned in one single sentence, and all it says is that the person doing the crafting needs a recipe. It doesn't describe how one might acquire one, or the rarity of these things.

Answer (score 1):

### Anything That Increases AC, HP, or Saving Throws

Keeping you alive means improving your chances to not take a hit, and improving your hit points so when you *do* take a hit, you won't go down.

At level 5, the DMG (page 135) suggests you should have "access" to common, uncommon, and rare items. With that in mind, here are some items to keep you alive.

- +AC items:  *+1 armour*, *bracers of defense*, *elven chain*, *ioun stone of protectin*, *ring of protection*
- +HP items: *Amulet of health*, *potion of healing/heroism*, *sword of life stealing*
- +Saving throw items: *mantle of spell resistance*, *potion of resistance*, *ring of evasion/resistance*
- Misc items: *Armour of resistance*, *belt of dwarvenkind* (both +HP and saving throws), *brooch of shielding*, *cloak of displacement*, *dust of disappearance*, *gloves of missile snaring*, *ioun stone of awareness*,  *ioun stone of reserve*, *periapt of heath/proof against poison/wound closure*, *potion of invulnerability*, *spell scrolls* of up to 5th level

### Items of Your Own Creation

Of course, you can work with your DM to make your own magic items (DMG284–5).

For example, the common *brooch of health* which allows you to cast *false life* once per day. Or the rare *bracelet of shielding* that has three charges that allows you to cast the *shield* spell.

Heck, with *reviivify* being a 3rd level spell, you can craft that into an uncommon item—higher, if you want it to auto-cast when you go down.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use 1st level spells:

   - Mage Armor: Base AC becomes 13 + its Dexterity modifier. (Lasts 8 hrs).
   - Shield: 1 reaction, which taken when hit by an attack. +5 bonus to AC, including against the triggering attack for 1 round.
2. Your party could have a member select a feat like:

   - Inspiring Leader: Spend 10 minutes inspiring companions ... each creature can gain temporary hit points equal to {party member with Inspiring Leader}'s (level +  Charisma modifier.)